# cross cluster replication in Redis

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have 3 Redis clusters each with 3 master nodes and 3 slave nodes. I want to make one of clusters as the primary cluster and the remaining two as the secondary cluster meaning data from the slave/master nodes of the primary cluster will be replicated to the master nodes of the secondary cluster.

In other words, data mapped to each slot of primary cluster would be replicated to corresponding slot of master node in secondary clusters.

Is there any simple way to achieve this? Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master nodes are separated by the concept of hashslot as mentioned here https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial, so replication of one master node to other makes no sense. For you use case you can simply have single master node with 2 slave nodes so that data replicated from master node(primary cluster) will be replicated to other slave nodes(secondary cluster).

Comment: Is there any solution for redis for cross cluster (sentinel based cluster) data replication?